# Error using R flextable package - cannot load temporary image file

Tags: r, flextable

I am trying to save a data frame as an image file using flextable, with the ultimate goal to plot it next to a ggplot object. Here is example of the code:

```
library(flextable)
ft <- flextable( head( mtcars ) )
ft <- autofit(ft)
tf <- tempfile(fileext = ".png")
save_as_image(ft, tf)
```

which returns the following error:

```
Could not load  file:///D:/Antonis/Documents/file:/C:/Users/Antonis/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpmgSSYv/file2510dc77c47.html
Error in webshot::webshot(url = sprintf("file://%s", tf), file = path,  : 
  webshot.js returned failure value: 1
In addition: Warning message:
In normalizePath(path.expand(path), winslash, mustWork) :
  path[1]="file://C:\Users\Antonis\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpmgSSYv\file2510dc77c47.html": The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect
```

It seems like the file path is incorrect. I tried to change the working directory with setwd:

```
setwd("C:/Users/Antonis/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpmgSSYv")
```

but the error persists:

```
Could not load  file:///C:/Users/Antonis/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpmgSSYv/file:/C:/Users/Antonis/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpmgSSYv/file25105e4f2c8b.html
Error in webshot::webshot(url = sprintf("file://%s", tf), file = path,  : 
  webshot.js returned failure value: 1
In addition: Warning message:
In normalizePath(path.expand(path), winslash, mustWork) :
  path[1]="file://C:\Users\Antonis\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpmgSSYv\file25105e4f2c8b.html": The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect
```

The same happens when I try to set the path through the tempfile command:

```
tf <- tempfile(tmpdir = "C:/Users/Antonis/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpmgSSYv", fileext = ".png")
```

The save_as_image help file also did not offer some insight.

The above code is quite generic and in fact it is drawn from a blog post, so my problem seems to be local. 
Any suggestions?

Comment: There is a bug with Windows version (the `file:///` is wrong...) I will fix that soon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure about `flextable`, but you can use `tableHTML` for this as an alternative. You can specify a file to save locally or it will be saved on a temp file automatically.

```
library(tableHTML)
mtcars %>%
 head() %>%
 tableHTML() %>%
 add_theme('scientific') %>%
 tableHTML_to_image()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this works indeed. I guess this is a different question, but: is there a way to combine your html output with another ggplot (like in flextable)?

Comment: Happy to help. No, currently it is not available, but definitely something to consider adding.I ll add it on github as a new feature.

Comment: Depends on how you want to combine them in HTML. Is it on a website, shiny, rmarkdown? Btw, for your previous question, I figured you could specify a file to save the tableHTML (argument `file` in `tableHTML_to_image`). Then read it as a raster with `png::readPNG` and then add it to the `cowplot::plot_grid` function. That should work and you can combine both.

Comment: It works indeed, thank you! In fact it works even without reading it as a raster.  After saving your image file, you can use ggdraw() + draw_image() to store the saved image as your second "plot", and then combine them using plot_grid().